# Crystal Report custom paper size not working on another pc

Tags: crystal-reports, resize

I developed a desktop application with crystal report and i set custom paper size. It working fine on my pc. After deploy setup, it can't working custom size which i had set on another pc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set /configure your custom page in each new server, because that page size is not installed in that printer.

Whenever custom page size comes, with new server you need to proceed the same thing.

Note: only on server you have to change where your application host, not all other pc.